# How to Enable Logging in DASK

Tags: logging, machine-learning, scheduler, dask, worker

I am running a dask-scheduler and two dask-workers , one Client. In the Python code I am running a gridsearchcv fit. i Want to see the communication between my system's worker and other system's worker

Answer (score 0):

In the file ~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml

Adding the following at the Beginning I got the logs

logging:
  distributed: debug
  distributed.client: debug
  distributed.worker: debug

Comment: Sorry, I must have had the previous location. http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see the communication between my system's worker and other system's worker

If your goal is to see communication, then I recommend using [Dask's dashboard](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html#dashboard) instead of relying on logs.

https://youtu.be/N_GqzcuGLCY